# Mapping all POST methods in antMatchers in spring

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

My application is with spring boot and i use to post all the form data to AngularJS. In Below code is all should be permitted but in that `/vacation/resources and /vacation/login` are of `HTTP Post TYPE`. Instead  of mapping all URL to antMatchers. i am in need of need of something similar to this:

```
.antMatchers("/login", "/",  "/vacation/resource", "/vacation/login").permitAll()
```

Should be solved by something similar instead of mapping all url to antMatchers: `.allowedMethods("POST")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ant matchers do support specifications with method

```
public C antMatchers(HttpMethod method, String... antPatterns) {
    return chainRequestMatchers(RequestMatchers.antMatchers(method, antPatterns));
}
```

so simply use `antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/*")`